# Simple GIS to Provide Urban Boundaries

Tags: postgis, google-maps, openstreetmap

I have an app built on top of Google Maps right now and everything works great.

I want to add one feature that seems exceedingly difficult. On my site, I want users to be able to type "Boston, MA" or something like that and have it find a boundary polygon for Boston and display it on the existing google map.

What is the simplest solution to this problem?

I was looking at installing PostGIS and OSM but that process seems like overkill for what I need.

Comment: like the boundary here http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=Boston,+MA&ll=42.307276,-71.003952&spn=0.317377,0.727158&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&hnear=Boston,+Suffolk,+Massachusetts,+United+States&gl=ca&t=m&z=11

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the coordinates for that polygon? Last time I checked, they didn't allow access to that information.

I need to some computation only within that polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way which i have been using for a long time is that set up an administrative areas or municipal boundaries table in your database and then call them with query to map as geojson...

for getting rapid result in postgresql, thegeom object should be indexed with gist and your text should be indexed with using gin. GIN(Generalized Inverted Index) index lookups are about three times faster than GiST(Generalized Search Tree).

with geodjango, i am getting information of center point at every map panning from   administrative areas as following code:

```
pnt = Point(x, y, srid=4326)
p = AdministrativeBoundries.objects.filter(thegeom__contains = pnt)
result = (%s %s %s %s) % (p.cname, p.tname, p.dname, p.type)
```

and some resources for you:

- Loading OpenStreetMap data into PostGIS, [here](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis)
- Build a simple GIS web application using GeoDjango and Google Maps, [here](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html)

Beside this, these can help you too..

- Using PHP/PostgresSQL with Google Maps API, [here](http://sites.google.com/site/mapperzmapdemo/)
- PostGIS RESTful Web Service Framework, [here](http://geojason.info/google-vector-layers/demos/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/)
- [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), [ST_AsKML](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsKML.html)
- GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps, [here](https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps)

i hope it helps you...